# How to check for multiple keys in a dictionary if they are set to None?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following which works but I'd like to see a more cleaner or pythonic way to do this.

```
if options_dict['cids'] is not None and options_dict['mergekeys'] is not None:
   # do something
```

The above will resolve to true if the keys 'cids' and 'mergekeys' exist. Is there a better way to do the above? Additionally, how can I also check the following at the same time.

```
if options_dict['cids'] is None and options_dict['mergekeys'] is None:
   # do something
```

It would be awesome if I could combine both of the above in the same if statement in a elegant    way.

Comment: When you say ```is None``` do you mean that the value is actually ```None``` or that there is no key ```'cids'```?

Comment: A key can be in the dictionary with the value `None`, or it may not be in the dictionary at all. Which of these cases do you want to check?

Comment: The keys 'cids' and 'mergekeys' exist and can have the value of None (they exist in the dictionary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if all(options_dict[x] is not None for x in ('cids', 'mergekeys')):
```

Although I personally think that your current solution is better.  It is clear and more efficient than this one.

If the length of yours is the problem, then you can simply break it up over multiple lines:

```
if options_dict['cids'] is not None and 
    options_dict['mergekeys'] is not None:
```

Or, make a shorter name for the dictionary:

```
dct = options_dict
if dct['cids'] is not None and dct['mergekeys'] is not None:
```

The `all` and generator expression solution should only be used for checking more keys than just two or three.

Comment: Literally 2 seconds behind you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to make a list of `bool`s telling if the corresponding option was `None`:

```
nones = [ options_dict[i] is None for i in [ 'cids', 'mergekeys' ] ]
```

Then you can use the `any` and `all` predicates to test if any or all are `None`:

```
if not any(nones):
    # not a single one was none

elif all(nones):
    # all were nones
```

Comment: The generator in iCodez answer is better as it allows for short circuiting -- although it's easy to change your `nones` to a generator expression :-)

Comment: But you cannot reset a generator, so again YMMV ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd probably do:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> my_dict = {"hey": 1, "ho": 2, "let's": 3, "go": None}
>>> my_keys = "hey", "ho"
>>> my_values = itemgetter(*my_keys)
>>> my_values(my_dict)
(1, 2)
>>> None not in my_values(my_dict)
True
>>> my_keys = "let's", "go"
>>> my_values = itemgetter(*my_keys)
>>> my_values(my_dict)
(3, None)
>>> None not in my_values(my_dict)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Truly the best way for the second in isolation is:

```
if options_dict['cids'] is options_dict['mergekeys'] is None:
```

Although personally for dispatch I would do:

```
# give meaningful name
flags = (options_dict['cids'] is None, options_dict['mergekeys'] is None)

if all(flags):
    ...

if not any(flags):
    ...

else:
    ...
```